# Change value only if one digit differs with R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to solve such a task that if only one digit of a price differs then the price should be changed with a mode price of an appropriate group. I already tried the code below, but it doesn't work correctly in particular cases:

```
  library("dplyr")

  Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
  }

  pp %>% 
  group_by(PPCODE, grp = sprintf('%.1f', PRICE)) %>%
  mutate(PRICE = Mode(PRICE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

dput of demo data set:

```
structure(list(OUTLETID = c("11N", "12B", "17C",                            
"44Oo", "1NN", "5CC", "AA1", "11A"), PPCODE = c(4623,                                                                             
4623, 4623, 4111, 4111, 4623, 4111, 4111), 
PRICE = c(1.45, 1.45, 1.45, 5.45, 5.45, 1.42, 5.03, 5.45)), 
row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the case of the first ppcode my code works fine - changes 1.42 to 1.45, as only one digit differs from majority of prices (that 2 and in rest cases 5) and it is counted as a typo and changed. But, my code also changes 5.03 to 5.45, but it shouldn't because there are already two digits different not only one. Also, seems that my code checks the only second decimal number, but I need that it would work if any single sign differs (for example if 1.55 and all other prices 1.45 it should be changed to 1.45 as only 4 and 5 differs; if one price 2.45 and all others 1.45 in the group, it also should be changed to 1.45 because only first digit differs, etc.).

Comment: may be look at levenshtein distance in package stringdist ..

Comment: @RonakShah I fixed it, were wrong brackets. Check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work. I've added a function to check how many digits are different and only update the value if you have a single digit change.

The second issue (it only checks the second decimal) is due to the additional grouping variable you introduced `grp = sprintf('%.1f', PRICE)` so I removed that. If you need that variable you can introduced at the end of the computation.

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  browser()
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

digits_different <- function(mode, price){
  mode <- str_split(format(mode, nsmall = 2), "")[[1]]
  price <- str_split(format(price, nsmall = 2), "")[[1]]

  sum(mode != price)
}

pp %>% 
  group_by(PPCODE) %>%
  summarise(MODE = Mode(PRICE)) %>% 
  right_join(pp, by = "PPCODE") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    PRICE = ifelse(digits_different(PRICE, MODE) == 1, MODE, PRICE)
    ) %>%
  select(-MODE) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly at least for me. It changes a price to mode even if all 3 digits differ from the mode price. @student

Comment: @AdolfMiszka Can you try now. I fixed the issue. I need to pre-calculate the mode.

Comment: it seems now to work better on this dummy data example, but I spotted one more issue. Some prices are like 8.4; 1.5, etc. But if for example, all prices are 1.4 and one price 1.49 in the group, it also should be changed to 1.4, but this code looks that can't deal in such cases. @student

Comment: @AdolfMiszka Fixed and simplified. I had half the issue handled before but forgot to add the other half.

Comment: Thanks for your investigations, but now it works worse than earlier. Now it changes to a mode not only if one digit differs. For example, I tried 1.51 and others 1.45 in a group and it changed everything to 1.45, although here two digits in price are different. @student

Comment: @AdolfMiszka Sorry. I removed the check for that in my last edit. I've put that back in. It should work as you specified now.